# Simulating lighting function of fixed pipeline, which role plays the material emission?

Tags: opengl, lighting

So, I am trying to port [this sample](https://github.com/MauriceGit/Partikel_accelleration_on_GPU) to jogl.

Kind of ironic because he is using compute shaders with deprecated opengl, but anyway, I'd like to emulate that.

He sets light:

- ambient
- diffuse
- specular
- cut-off
- exponent

Material:

- ambient
- diffuse
- specular
- shininess
- emission

I found an almost perfect [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Specular_Highlights), where all the parameters he sets are cited, but one, the material emission

I also found another nice [link](http://www.sccg.sk/~samuelcik/opengl/opengl_07.pdf) where I can see all the default values for the fixed pipeline and I am going to use them to set what he doesn't.

So, where (and how) shall I insert the material emission in the function?

Edit: for the undervoter, I find it hard being more clear and explicit than the question above, maybe if you tell me what you did not comprehend I can try to help you, but you should have some basic notions about opengl and lighting first in order to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emission color is similar to the ambient color, in the sense that both of them are used for terms that are independent of the light/normal directions.

The overall lighting calculation can be expressed as a sum of different terms:

```
emission + ambient + diffuse + specular
```

The difference between emission and ambient is:

- The material emission color is used directly as a term in the overall lighting calculation.
- The material ambient color is multiplied with the light model ambient color, and the ambient colors of each active light source. These terms are then all summed up to obtain the overall ambient contribution.

For details, check out the section "The Mathematics of Lighting" in the Red Book, which is available for free online ([direct link to the section](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html#name7)).

Comment: Thanks Reto for the answer and the link ;)